# Starting an activity for result with launchMode="singleTop" behaves differently on Android 11 than on Android 12

Tags: android, startactivityforresult, launchmode, onnewintent

I have an Activity with `android:launchMode="singleTop"`.

When I start it for result I get different behavior depending on the Android version:

- **Android 12 and later**: The on top of Activity is reused and just gets a call to `onNewIntent()`
  → *Expected behavior*, because the Activity is declared as `singleTop` and is already on top of the Activity stack.
- **Android 11 & 10 (and probably lower)**: A new instance of the Activity is created.
  → *Unexpected behavior*, it behaves as if `launchMode` was `standard`.

When I start the Activity regularly (not for result), it works as expected also for Android 11 & 10 (and probably lower).

I couldn't find any mention of this in the Android release notes or migration guides.

Why is that so?

I tried it with and without `ActivityCompat`. Here is a code example that demonstrates it quite well:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.i("TestLaunchMode", "onCreate")
        setContent {
            TestLaunchModeTheme {
                Column {
                    val activity = this@MainActivity
                    val options: Bundle? = null
                    val intent = Intent(activity, MainActivity::class.java)
                    Text(
                        text = "Start (compat)",
                        modifier = Modifier.clickable { ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options) },
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "Start",
                        modifier = Modifier.clickable { activity.startActivity(intent, options) },
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "Start for Result (compat)",
                        modifier = Modifier.clickable { ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(activity, intent, 1, options) },
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "Start for Result",
                        modifier = Modifier.clickable { activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1, options) },
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        Log.i("TestLaunchMode", "onNewIntent")
    }
}
```

Because `MainActivity` has its `launchMode` set to `singleTop` in the `AndroidManifest` I expect the string *onCreate* to be logged only once when initially starting the App/Activity. All button clicks should log *onNewIntent* instead.

However on Android 11 & 10 (and probably lower) it logs *onCreate* when starting the activity for result.

Is there a way to make it work as it is documented? So that I get the same behaviour on Android 11 (and lower) as on Android 12 (and later)?

Comment: Well ok. Thanks for the info. And is there a problem? Any questions? Can you handle the difference?

Comment: Well my problem is, that the Activity isn't opened as expected (reused) for Android 10 & 11 and this breaks the app... Our whole app architecture relies on the launchTypes working as documented.

Comment: Mmm.. In MainActivity you start another MainActivity (for result or not). And with that you expect to stay in the original activity. I do not understand this use.

Comment: It stems from an abstraction layer. Our navigation is very dynamic and uses a simplified navigation layer that abstracts away from Activities and Fragments. Under the hood these Activity calls happen each time the page changes. Based on the launchType we want to either create a new Activity when navigating ("standard") or just replace the Fragment in the current Activity ("singleTop").