# Google Files not respecting singleInstance launchMode

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My main `Activity` is defined as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.bjornfelle.redacted.MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
```

I also have an `intent filter` for importing images as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

If I share an image with my app from a third party file manager, say CxFileExplorer, it switches to the currently running instance of my app if any, or launches it if not. This is desired behaviour.

If I do the same thing but share the file from Google Files, a new instance of my app is spawned within Google Files regardless of whether or not it is already running. This breaks things with my app and is not the desired behaviour.

If I remove `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` from my `Activity` definition, even CxFileExplorer spawns an additional instance of the app if it's already running. So I know this flag is doing something, it just seems that Google Files is not respecting it. Is there something else I can do to prevent this behaviour so that the app will truly be single instance, or do I need to code around this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78077024/starting-an-activity-for-result-with-launchmode-singletop-behaves-differently?noredirect=1#comment137650765_78077024

Comment: @blackapps - thank you, though I'm running Android 13 and the asker of the question you linked to was saying that this issue was affecting Android 10 and 11. I did find another post, but the solution given in the one answer didn't work, and from the posted code, I can't see how it's switching to the main activity and then killing the newly spawned one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750124/launchmode-being-overriden-by-google-files-app-when-sharing-new-instance-of-a-s

Comment: Use an app like Intent Intercept to find out which flags are set by the calling app.

Comment: @blackapps - thanks, I didn't know about that tool. If I send the intent from Google Files, the flags are `FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET` . Sending from CxFileExplorer uses the same flags plus `FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND`. I tried adding this flag manually to the intent but it made no difference, I guess it's too late by that point as the activity has already been created :/

Comment: @bjørnfelle did you get anywhere with this -> Im finding a similar issue with google files. stackoverflow.com/questions/78209973/… In my case, I am using a react native share menu library, but the issue is an android one. It has the code shown in that link, which is what is part of the problematic issue with the files app for me

Comment: sorry this link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78209973/android-sharing-files-from-other-apps-to-my-app-react-native-but-is-probably